# Laravel "with" does not work currently next to "get" method

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Laravel `with` does not work currently next to `get` method when `get` has argument

I have two table that has one-to-many relationship.
[image]

I wrote this code:

```
Page::with('user:id,name')->get();
```

[image]

that work currently, but I want specific columns from `pages` table (such as `title` and `body`) so I wrote this code:

```
Page::with('user:id,name')->get(['title', 'body']);
```

But `user` will be `null`

[image]

Comment: Page::select('title', 'body')->with('user')->get();

Comment: user will be null

Comment: use this, you have to retrieve the id also:
Page::select('id','title', 'body')->with('user')->get();

Comment: The result made no difference

Comment: it should, do you have the relation in your model? like page hasOne user?

Comment: you have to make sure to select the `user_id` field for the relationship as well in that `get` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the `user_id` field from `pages`. That is the field that is used to then get the Users associated with all the Pages that the query would return. It is separate queries. How can Eloquent do a query to get all the Users that the Posts belong to if there is no `user_id` field to use?

```
Page::with('user:id,name')->get(['title', 'body', 'user_id']);
```

This would mean all the returned Page results/objects would have a `user_id` column that it can then pluck from the Collection to then do a query to load all the Users and then match them back to their parents.

The `get` method is defining your `SELECT`, as this is the definition of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder@get`:

```
public function get($columns = ['*'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `select()` and you need to add foreign key also

```
Page::with('user:id,name'=> function($query) { $query->select('title','body','UserId'); }])->get();   // If foreign key is `UserId` you should use your column name here
```

Comment: It does not work too